# Purpose of decltype-specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, decltype

I'm reading the clause about qualified name lookup. There is a quote from thereout:

> If a :: scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not
>   preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup of the name preceding that ::
>   considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations
>   are types.

As defined in the standard `decltype-specifier` is:

```
decltype-specifier:
    decltype ( expression )
    decltype ( auto )
```

By what does it mean? Can you explain purpose of that keyword?

Comment: Read [this article](http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_01.html). The author is concentrating on the differences between `decltype` and `auto`, but it is a fascinating read nevertheless, and provides insight into the functioning of both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`decltype` is one of the new keywords introduced with C++11. **It is a specifier that returns the type of an expression**.

It is particularly useful in template programming to retrieve the type of expressions that depends on template parameters or return types.

Examples from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
struct A {
   double x;
};
const A* a = new A{0};

decltype( a->x ) x3;       // type of x3 is double (declared type)
decltype((a->x)) x4 = x3;  // type of x4 is const double& (lvalue expression)

template <class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u); // return type depends on template parameters
```

As for the second specifier version, it will be allowed in C++14 to make some tedious `decltype` declarations easier to read:

```
decltype(longAndComplexInitializingExpression) var = longAndComplexInitializingExpression;  // C++11

decltype(auto) var = longAndComplexInitializingExpression;  // C++14
```

**Edit:**

`decltype` can naturally be used with the scope operator.

Example from [this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986932/purpose-of-decltype-specifier/23987037?noredirect=1#comment36962648_23987037):

```
struct Foo { static const int i = 9; };

Foo f;
int x = decltype(f)::i;
```

Your quote of the standard specify that in that case, the lookup of the name for `decltype(f)` does not consider only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types. This is because in this case, the name lookup is transferred to the `decltype` operator itself.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. But I still don't understand how does decltype-specifier affect on the qualified-name-lookup. Can you get an example?

Comment: Sure, I added an edit that shows an example with the scope operator